# Program compiles fine in javac but not in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to test a java library I found online. I'm testing each component separately, and they work correctly on the command line when I do `javac *.java` followed by `java test`. This works perfectly fine, but if I try to build the same `test.java` file in IntelliJ 2017, it seems to build other irrelevant source files also present in the project and fails since they require dependencies that are not present (but I just want to compile and run `test.java`.)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: more information is required.  do you get an error? what does it say? did you tell IntelliJ where the sources (java code) is located? there is not enough info to help at this point

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the library you are using, so this may or may not work for you...

- In the Project panel of Intellij IDEA select the class of the *.java file you want to compile/run.
- Right-click, and on the popup menu you should see a couple of entries that look something like this:

  1. Recompile 'Test.java' (That entry may or may not be present.)
  2. Run 'Test.main()' (That entry will be present as long as you have a main() method.)

See the screen shot below for clarification.

Do you see similar entries?...

- If so, what happens when you select them?
- If not, please update the OP with more information on the error you are getting.

[image]